# Why does datetime.utcnow().timestamp() return different values for Python and IPython in the same environment and terminal

Tags: python, datetime, ipython, utc

In IPython:

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Sep  4 2017, 13:34:02) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
Out[1]: 1515396403.049774
```

In Python:

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Sep  4 2017, 13:34:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
1515425220.215077
>>>
```

The result from IPython appears to be in my timezone instead of UTC.

Without the call to `.timestamp()` the values returned by `.utcnow()` are the same in both terminals. Why can this be the case?

In a regular Python prompt, the values for `datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` and `datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()` are different.

```
Python 3.6.2 (default, Sep  4 2017, 13:34:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
1515548420.130655
>>> datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
1515577235.982597
```

In IPython, these values are the same.

In IPython `now` and `utcnow` return the same. In Python, `now` returns my local time.

```
In [4]: datetime.utcnow()
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 10, 1, 44, 55, 496083)

In [5]: datetime.now()
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 10, 1, 45, 53, 811077)
```

Python:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 9, 17, 46, 29, 754642)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 10, 1, 46, 32, 865136)
```

Comment: what is the result without `.timestamp()`?

Comment: @AyushGupta Interestingly, utcnow() returns the same in both prompts without `timestamp()`! What does this mean?

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp): "Naive datetime instances are assumed to represent local time and this method relies on the platform C `mktime()` function to perform the conversion." I'd say that IPython is confused about your timezone.

Comment: @Skylar can you post the result of utcnow() in both platforms

Comment: @MarkRansom it's actually python that is confused apparently (updating ...)

Comment: As I said, IPython is confused about your timezone - it thinks you're in UTC. Otherwise `now` and `utcnow` would return different results.

Comment: @SkylarSaveland did you figure out what was causing the discrepancy?

Answer (score 1):

When `datetime.timestamp()` is called on a timezone-naive instance of `datetime`, it assumes the value is a local datetime. Therefore, the code `datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` should never be used, since the non-local timezone-naive `datetime.utcnow()` violates that assumption.

The "old" correct way to get the UTC timestamp is:
`datetime.now().timestamp()`

A better way of doing it is to avoid the naive datetime, using the timezone-aware version, formerly using:
`datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()`
or now, because `datetime.utcnow()` has been deprecated since Python version 3.12, using:
`datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp()`

A fairly easy way to see the effect is with the following code in an environment where the timezone offset is non-zero:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
now1 = datetime.now()
now2 = datetime.utcnow()
now3 = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
now1
now1.timestamp()
now2
now2.timestamp() # WRONG!
now3
now3.timestamp()
```

This produces output like this:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> now1 = datetime.now()
>>> now2 = datetime.utcnow()
>>> now3 = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
>>> now1
datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 16, 11, 50, 0, 979519)
>>> now1.timestamp()
1702749000.979519
>>> now2
datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 16, 17, 50, 0, 982995)
>>> now2.timestamp() # WRONG!
1702770600.982995
>>> now3
datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 16, 17, 50, 0, 983405, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> now3.timestamp()
1702749000.983405
```

As can be seen above, when using the "old" way with the timezone-naive local datetime `now1`, `timestamp()` applies the timezone offset, resulting in the UTC timestamp value. Likewise, the "better" way with the timezone-aware `now3` datetime, `timestamp()` produces the same result. Note that without the timezone info, the value of `now2` does not appear much different than the value of `now1` except that it is 6 hours ahead. Since `now2` has already applied the timezone offset once when `utcnow()` was called, calling `timestamp()` on the timezone-naive value applies the timezone offset a second time, resulting in a timestamp value where the timezone offset has been applied twice! In the example above, the time zone was 6 hours west of UTC, resulting in a timestamp that was actually 12 hours ahead of local time and therefore, incorrectly, 6 hours (21,600 seconds) *ahead* of UTC.